# How can i change my response body timestamp format to unix timestamp?

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, response

I have an exception class which is annotated with `@ResponseStatus` so when I throw this exception a particular response is returned. It works fine but I have a problem with a timestamp: "timestamp": "2019-02-12T13:33:26.540+0000" I would like to have timestamp in unix seconds "1550038291". How can I change so milliseconds are used in response?

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, reason = "Invalid authorization")
public class AuthorizationException extends RuntimeException {}
```

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-02-12T13:33:26.540+0000",
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Invalid authorization",
  "path": "/my-endpoint"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCiA2.png)

write-dates-as-timestamps= true

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEX8z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own implementation of this interface in order to change response
 - AuthenticationFailureHandler

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler
{
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("timestamp", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()); // you can format your date here 
    data.put("status",HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    data.put("message", "You are not authorized.");
    data.put("path", request.getRequestURL().toString());

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, data);
    out.flush();
  }
}
```

You need to Configure this `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.java` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("your.base.package")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
 @Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
    ;
}

@Bean
public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
}
```